# crystal reports does not load after deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I have created a window application in vs 2010,framework 4.0. using C#. 
My PC is window X P, 32 bit. I have use 4-5 crystal reports in the project. 
All reports are working fine when i run the program locally means in debugging mode. But when I  install the setup project, crystal report stop working. It doesn't showing any
 error but It hangs the whole system. 
I have searched in Google a lot but not got any specific solution. 
I had installed crystal report run time version, yet its not working.  What should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

have you installed Crystal reports on server where you are deploying your application?

Comment: I am installing it in my PC. I had installed crystal report version for vs 2010 and also run time version.

Comment: Code of which part? I had used crystal report viewer and data set as data source of crystal report. It works fine in debug mode. Problem is creating after deployment.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest install this package on deployment server CR Redistributable package CRRedist2008
i hope this will solve your issue and also have a look at this post hope this will your help too http://www.actualinstaller.com/help/crystal-reports.html

Comment: i am using crystal report version 13 and i had already installed SAP Crystal Reports 32 bit redistributable package (SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET framework). yet its not working.